# If Bob wants to make sure Alice knows a second message came from him, what key or method should Bob use?

Tags: public-key

If Bob wants to make sure Alice knows a second message came from him (not caring if only Alice can read it), what key or method should Bob use?

Answer (score 1):

Bob could send a public key with the first message. The second message can then be signed with the private key by Bob and verified using the public key by Alice.

This of course requires some kind of trust that the first message indeed came from Bob.

Comment: Or the first message could contain a hash over the second message :P

Answer (score 1):

To add to Maarten's answer above, this is how you would go about a secure method of doing this on a unix system with GPG:

Bob generates a keypair:

```
bob% gpg --gen-key    
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) DSA and ElGamal (default)
   (2) DSA (sign only)
   (4) ElGamal (sign and encrypt)
Your selection?
```

Bob gets his fingerprint and shares it with alice in a trusted channel:

```
bob% gpg --fingerprint bob@mail.com
pub  1024D/9E98BC16 1999-06-04 bob <bob@mail.com>
             Fingerprint: 268F 448F CCD7 AF34 183E  52D8 9BDE 1A08 9E98 BC16
```

Bob then signs a document with his private key:

`bob% gpg --clearsign doc`

..so alice can verify the document against bob's public key:

```
alice% gpg --verify doc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jun  4 12:38:46 1999 CDT using DSA key ID 9E98BC16 
gpg: Good signature from "Bob <bob@mail.com>"
```